# Will an expression comprising only an identifier read a volatile variable?

Tags: c, volatile, standards

I'm writing for a microcontroller (dsPIC24) using Microchip's compiler. The peripheral devices are all memory-mapped variables. Occasionally it is necessary to clear a buffer by reading from it, which I usually do with just:

```
SPI1BUF;
```

...where `SPI1BUF` is declared `volatile char` in Microchip's headers. It works for me, but now I'm curious: is it standardised behaviour? I recall that if I perform an assignment:

```
unsigned char x = SPI1BUF;
```

...the standard says that the volatile variable *must* be read. But is this also true for the identifier-as-the-whole-expression case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such a bare expression is a statement type called an "expression statement" in the C standard.  The relevant section of the standard (6.8.3) says:

> The expression in an expression
>   statement is evaluated as a void
>   expression for its side effects.

Reading the value of a `volatile`-qualified variable is considered such a side effect, so it can't be elided, per §5.1.2.3:

> Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or
>   calling a function that does any of those operations are all side
>   effects, which are changes in the state of the execution environment.

Assuming that `SPI1BUF` is an lvalue (this is true both if it is an identifier, or a macro that expands to an invocation of the unary `*` operator), §6.3.2.1 has this to say:

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the unary `&`
>   operator, the `++` operator, the `--` operator, or the left operand of
>   the `.` operator or an assignment operator, an lvalue that does not
>   have array type is converted to the value stored in the designated
>   object (and is no longer an lvalue).

Since none of the exceptions apply, this assures us that the underlying (volatile) object is "Accessed", because the lvalue has been converted to the value stored in the object, which obviously necessitates *accessing* the value of that object.

In summary: yes, this is standard behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the terminology too :)

Comment: @curiousguy: No, it is correct.  §5.1.2.3 says: *"Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function that does any of those operations are all side effects, which are changes in the state of the execution environment."*

Comment: @curiousguy: The part of the standard I quoted in the answer says explicitly that the expression is evaluated.  During the evaluation of the expression, the lvalue `SPI1BUF` is converted to the value stored in the underlying object as per §6.3.2.1.

Comment: @caf Thanks for this explanation. It makes sense (in a crazy ISO C way).

Comment: @curiousguy: Thankyou too for the discussion, I think my answer has been improved as a result.

Comment: But this may not work in C++. (Yes, the question is tagged C and not C++.)